# R print object to file

Tags: r

In R, is there any way to print an object, such as summary of a linear model, to a txt file?
print() can print out the object nicely but I can't find a way to redirect the output.
cat() on the other hand don't seem to be able to handle lists, I got this error back:

```
Error in cat(summary(lin_model), file = paste0(output_dir, "/linear_model_output.txt")) : 
  argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'
```

Comment: maybe `?capture.output` e.g. `capture.output(summary(lm(1:10~1)), file="test.txt")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `sink()` prior to and after your `print`. The first call contains the path to your output file.

In your case:

```
sink(file.path(output_dir, "linear_model_output.txt"))
print(summary(lin_model))
sink()
```